# how to modify php config class file like in joomla?

Tags: php, class, config

for example, i have "config.php":

```
<?php
        class Config {
            public $var1 = 'ex1';
            public $var2 = 'ex2';
            }
?>
```

and i have "index.php"

```
<?php
   include ('config.php');
   $a = new Config();
   $a->var1='changed_ex1';
   $a->var2='changed_ex2';
   UPDATE($a,'config.php');
?>
```

so here is the question - what shoud be in UPDATE function to write changes into config.php?=)

Answer (score 1):

I highly do not recommend writing files to store configuration. I'd rather store config in the database if I need to change the settings during runtime.

But if you insist on your chosen path, your UPDATE function will need to read the entire file and either regex-replace the necessary keys, or simply re-render the entire thing based on stored data and the data you need to change.